# why this inequality holds

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $f,g\in C(\overline{\Omega},\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then why we have
$$
dist(b,g(\partial\Omega))\geq dist(b,f(\partial\Omega))-\Vert g-f\Vert
$$
where $dist$ is the distance between a point and a set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and 
$$
\Vert f\Vert=\sup_{x\in\overline{\Omega}}|f(x)|
$$
with $\vert\cdot\vert$ the usual Euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$d(b,g(\partial \Omega))=\inf_{x\in \partial \Omega}|b-g(x)|;\quad d(b,f(\partial \Omega))=\inf_{x\in \partial \Omega}|b-f(x)| $$
Triangle inequality:
$$|b-g(x)|\geq |b-f(x)|-|g(x)-f(x)|\qquad \forall x\in\partial \Omega $$
Take the $\inf$ over $x\in \partial \Omega$ on both terms:
\begin{align*}d(b,g(\partial \Omega))&\geq d(b,f(\partial \Omega))-\inf_{x\in \partial \Omega}|g(x)-f(x)|\geq d(b,f(\partial \Omega))-\sup_{x\in \partial{\Omega}}|g(x)-f(x)|\geq \\ 
&\geq d(b,f(\partial \Omega))-\sup_{x\in \overline{\Omega}}|g(x)-f(x)|=d(b,f(\partial \Omega))-\|g-f\|
\end{align*}

Comment: Sorry, but I wonder why it holds that $\sup_{x,y\in \overline{\Omega}}|g(x)-f(y)|=\|g-f\|$. Could you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: Yeah, it's not true. $\|g-f\|=\sup_{x\in \overline{\Omega}}|g(x)-f(x)|\leq \sup_{x,y\in \overline{\Omega}}|g(x)-f(y)|$.  So the last inequality does not hold. I'm thinking about how to fix this.

Comment: It should work like this? I eliminated the $y$. I don't know why I used two variables in the first place, lol.